# How to stop spending broadcast in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I have an Android project which is sending a Broadcast every second and am trying to figure out how to stop it after a click.

My broadcast code is:

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent ("send broadcast");
sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
stoptimertask(); //it is stopping broadcast for a second.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define two methods: one that start a [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer) to send a broadcast every second and a second one that stop the Timer.

```
Timer timer;

private void startBroadcastLoop() {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Send broadcast
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent ("send broadcast");
            sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }

    },0,1000); // Send broadcast every second
}

private void stopBroadcastLoop() {
    if(timer!=null){
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }    
}
```

And then on your button, call the right function according to the state of a boolean:

```
sendBroadcastBool = false;
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // If broadcast not sent yet
            if (!sendBroadcastBool) {
                startBroadcastLoop();
                sendBroadcastBool = true;
            }
            else {
                stopBroadcastLoop();
                sendBroadcastBool = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Best

Comment: Please Maxouille can you please help me for my another android problem? I have posted an question bit I didn't get an answer till now. Problem is desktop pages in android web view not showing like Android Chrome Browser. Please! Please! Please!

Comment: I'm not familiar with webview but I'll take a look.